# Shared module is not available for eager consumption Angular 16

Tags: angular, webpack, nomachine-nx, angular-module-federation

I am using nx and module federation webpack plugin. I had upgrade angular from version 13 to 16 then I recive error

**Shared module is not available for eager consumption**

I try a lot of configurations of module-federation.config.js

Current config is

```
 module.exports = {
      name: 'llp-landing-page',
      remotes: [],
      additionalShared: [
        {
          libraryName: '@angular/core',
          sharedConfig: {
            singleton: true,
            strictVersion: true,
            eager: true
          }
        },
        {
          libraryName: '@angular/common',
          sharedConfig: {
            singleton: true,
            strictVersion: true,
            eager: true
          }
        },
        {
          libraryName: '@angular/router',
          sharedConfig: {
            singleton: true,
            strictVersion: true,
            eager: true
          }
        },
        {
          libraryName: '@angular/platform-browser',
          sharedConfig: {
            singleton: true,
            strictVersion: true,
            eager: true
          }
        },
        {
          libraryName: 'url-search-params-polyfill',
          sharedConfig: {
            singleton: true,
            strictVersion: true,
            eager: true
          }
        },
        {
          libraryName: 'focus-visible',
          sharedConfig: {
            singleton: true,
            strictVersion: true,
            eager: true
          }
        },
        {
          libraryName: 'rxjs',
          sharedConfig: {
            singleton: true,
            strictVersion: true,
            eager: true
          }
        },
        {
          libraryName: 'rxjs/operators',
          sharedConfig: {
            singleton: true,
            strictVersion: true,
            eager: true
          }
        },
        {
          libraryName: '@angular/common/http',
          sharedConfig: {
            singleton: true,
            strictVersion: true,
            eager: true
          }
        },
        {
          libraryName: 'internal-data-access-swagger',
          sharedConfig: {
            singleton: true,
            strictVersion: false,
            eager: true
          }
        }
      ],
    };
```

For external libraries that are located inside node modules, the error disappeared when I added them to additionalShared. Issue still exist for internal library which is located in the lib folder